# How to throw the set state to global variable

Tags: reactjs

I want to throw the value to const countBadge, but i have encountered an error undefined. How would I be able to set what ever the data i have fetched to global variable? and i need to export the new value

the fetching of data was right, because on other part i console.log the result[0].NumToApprove and it has a value of 7.

```
const countBadge = this.state.numToApprove

class Notifications extends Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      numToApprove: 0,
    }
  }
  fetchData = () =>{
    fetch(APILink + '/filing/get_badges', {
      method: 'POST',
      credentials: 'include',
      headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
      },
      body: qs.stringify({
        'is_from_api': true
      })
      })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then((result) => {
          this.setState({
            numToApprove: result[0].NumToApprove
          })
        }).catch(error => {
          alert('Transaction Error' + error)
        }
      );
  }
}

export { countBadge }
```

Comment: countBadge would never have any value, as 'this.state' won't exist outside the class.

Comment: you can use the `countBadge` variable inside the constructor by `this.countBadge = this.state.numToApprove`

Comment: You probably don't want to set a global variable. Global variables are best avoided when writing clear code, you should avoid using context in most cases. In particular, think twice before using it to "save typing" and using it instead of passing explicit props.

Answer (score 1):

So first, you're using `this` outside of your component which will not evaluate to your component, so `countBadge` won't hold the `numToApprove` that's in your component.

Then, if you want to change its value, you should use `let` and not `const`.

So something like this should do :

```
let countBadge = 0

class Notifications extends Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      numToApprove: 0,
    }
  }
  fetchData = () =>{
    fetch(APILink + '/filing/get_badges', {
      method: 'POST',
      credentials: 'include',
      headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
      },
      body: qs.stringify({
        'is_from_api': true
      })
      })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then((result) => {
          this.setState({
            numToApprove: result[0].NumToApprove
          })
          countBadge = /* ... the new value ... */
        }).catch(error => {
          alert('Transaction Error' + error)
        }
      );
  }
}

export { countBadge }
```

Then, if you want another component to be updated once `countBadge` has changed, the solution is not to put it as a global variable, because global variables don't trigger UI updates when they change.
Instead, there are two solutions :

- put `countBadge` in the state of the closest common ancestor of `Notifications` and the other component
- use Redux

Comment: it returns zero not the actual value

Comment: if you want it to always match ```numToApprove``` state and read it in another component which is not a child, the only solution is to put it in a state higher in the component hierarchy